# How to chain data attribute and disabled selector in tailwind?

Tags: css, css-selectors, tailwind-css

I have an button with data-loading=true and disabled attributes. I need to write a style in tailwind that applies only if data-loading!=true and disabled.

```
<button data-loading='true' disabled>Submit</button>
```

Tried (not working)

```
disabled:not(data-[loading=true]):bg-red
```

Comment: `:not(data-[loading=true])` - the square brackets are absolutely clearly _off_ here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`disabled:` variant](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#disabled) for when an element would match the `:disabled` pseudo-class.

For when `data-loading` is not the value of `true`, you can use an [arbitrary variant](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#using-arbitrary-variants) with `:not()` and an attribute selector: `[&:not([data-loading=true])]:`.

To combine these two, you can chain them separately:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.5"></script>

<button data-loading='true' disabled class="[&:not([data-loading=true])]:disabled:bg-red-500">Submit</button>
<button data-loading='false' disabled class="[&:not([data-loading=true])]:disabled:bg-red-500">Submit</button>
```

Or you can have the `:disabled` pseudo class in the arbitrary variant instead of the built-in variant:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.5"></script>

<button data-loading='true' disabled class="[&:not([data-loading=true]):disabled]:bg-red-500">Submit</button>
<button data-loading='false' disabled class="[&:not([data-loading=true]):disabled]:bg-red-500">Submit</button>
```